# Mega Menu Width

Tags: mega-menu

I have a mega menu that's supposed to have a fixed width within certain boundaries. I am discussing with my designer and developer colleagues cases where the content of the mega menu increases in width.

Our options are:

1. Wrap the content in the mega menu in order to keep the mega menu's width preserved.

[image]

2. Allow the mega menu to expand horizontally to a certain limit which is wider than the alignment with the top menu. It's worth noting that the expansion will have to be to the left.

[image]

I'd appreciate your thoughts on the issue.

Answer (score 11):

I would place the top menu below the Logo making use of the full width of the browser window and not wrapping the text. You get more balance in your viewport, don't cover the logo and make room for possible sign in | register links as well as a search field at the very top. Like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6cxnF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I would add that if you are still constrained, that you then either need to: rethink the copywriting of the menu items; remove some of the menu items; or wrap the text.  In that order.

Comment: @JohnGB That's a really good point. Adding to that list - think of labeling and the possibility to decrease the numbers of characters used in the label.

Comment: Thanks Benny for your response. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work because the logo we are dealing with is ridiculously large and wide and our client's Branding requires that we deal with it. Your solution would cause a lot of empty space and would push the content down. We've already added a strip where login and search are available to the top of what I have shown you. But thanks for your input.

Comment: I should add that the website is not for my company. We are designing for a third party and we are trying to cater all cases that they may go through and attempting to remove as many restrictions as possible!

Comment: @Tarek If you try to cater for all cases, the only option is to wrap.  It also means that you have to choose a potentially worse design just in case someone wants something.

Comment: @Tarek - I believe using the full width is the way, so let's not kill the idea yet. Can you try to put the navigation ABOVE the logo? It's not very common attitude, but with some design skills could do the trick. Plus, you could make the menu sticky and keep it at the top of the screen regardless scrolling just like on http://techcrunch.com/

Comment: It has been discussed previously here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22200/navigation-above-site-header